Assistance Required for Identifying Persistent Android Auto Device Identifiers Across Connections
We are building an Android application that integrates with Android Auto to provide a tailored user experience based on the connected vehicle. Our goal is to implement a feature that identifies if a user is connected to their vehicle via Android Auto and displays a list of available Android Auto-enabled devices (typically just one). The user would then select their vehicle from this list.
For the app's enhanced functionality, we need a way to retrieve a unique identifier for the vehicle/device that remains consistent across reconnections. This identifier should be accessible regardless of the connection type, whether over Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, or USB.
We have not been able to locate the appropriate APIs in the current documentation to fulfill this requirement. Could you guide us on whether there is an API or method to obtain a persistent identifier for Android Auto devices? Any insights or documentation links that might assist us in achieving this would be greatly appreciated.
Android Code snippet to access unique identifier for connected Android Auto device
sudo code

Get Connected Android Auto Device
Extract unique identifier, possibly something like serial number
When next time app starts, get the connected android auto match it with saved identifier to determine if it is same vehicle or not.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
